Do there exists $n$ subsets of $[n]$, with intersection of size at most $1$ , and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} |A_i | \gg \sqrt{n}? $
Do there exists $n$ subsets $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$  of $ [n]$, such that $|A_i \cap A_j| \leq 1$ for all $1\leq i<j\leq n$, and
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} |A_i | \gg \sqrt{n}?
$$
Here, $f(n)\gg g(n)$ means that $f(n)\in \Omega(g(n))$ as $n\to\infty$, that is $\exists C\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(n)\ge C\cdot  g(n)$ for $n$ large enough.
A similar question has been asked a couple of times before. Here we are asking about the tightness of the inequality. Hence, instead of $\ll$ for all, we are asking  does there exists such sets such that $\gg$ is valid.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Yes, such sets always exist.
First, suppose that there exists a prime number $p$ such that $n=p^2+p+1$. In that case, there exists a projective plane with $n$ points and $n$ lines, where each line contains $p+1$ points. You can let $A_k$ be the $k^\text{th}$ line for each $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. The definition of a projective plane ensures that $|A_i\cap A_j|=1$ when $i\neq j$. Furthermore, $\frac1n \sum |A_i|=p+1\ge \sqrt n$, as required.
What about when $n$ is not of the form $p^2+p+1$? Find the largest prime number $p$ such that $p^2+p+1\le n$, and let $m=p^2+p+1$. Necessarily, $$p\ge \frac12(\sqrt{n}-1).$$ This is because Bertrand's postulate guarantees there exists a prime in the interval $\big(\frac12\lfloor \sqrt{n}-1\rfloor ,\lfloor \sqrt {n}-1 \rfloor\big)$, and for every $q$ in this interval, we have $q^2+q+1\le (\sqrt{n}-1)^2+(\sqrt n-1)+1\le n$.
First, we will apply the construction in the previous paragraph to $\{1,\dots,m\}$, producing sets $A_1,\dots,A_m$ each with size $p+1$ such that $|A_i\cap A_j|=1$ when $i\neq j$. Then, for each $k\in \{m+1,m+2,\dots,n\}$, we define $A_k$ to be the singleton set $\{k\}$. Then
$$
\frac1n\sum_i |A_i|=\frac1n\big(m\cdot (p+1)+(n-m)\cdot 1\big)
$$
Using the fact that $p\ge \frac12(\sqrt{n}-1)$ and $m=p^2+p+1$, it is easy to see that $\frac1n \sum_i |A_i|= \Omega(\sqrt n)$.
